# ReactJS image/pdf file download not working

Tags: reactjs, file, download, response, pyramid

I want to download file that can be in any format viz. pdf, jpeg, png, xlsx, csv etc. The download API on backend using pyramid framework is sending FileResponse as below:

```
def delivery_item_download_view(request, *args, **kw):
    context = request.context
    item_row = context.item_row

    if item_row and item_row["deleted_at"] is None:
        print(request.upload_dir+'/'+item_row["file_name"]+'.'+item_row["file_extension"])
        response = FileResponse(
            request.upload_dir+'/'+item_row["file_name"]+'.'+item_row["file_extension"],
            request=request,
        )
        response.headers["attachment"] = item_row["name"];
        return response
```

This, when executed using POSTMAN works as expected giving file as output. However,when tried implementing same using ReactJS, it's not working as expected. My client-code is as below:

```
onDownloadItem= (item) => {
    console.log("item id is:", item.item_id)
    var apiBaseUrl = "https://dev.incodax.com/api/deliveries_items/"+ item.item_id+ "/download";
    fetch(apiBaseUrl, {
        method: "GET",
    }).then((res) => {
        fileDownload(res,item.file_name)
        console.log(res)
    })
}
```

This fileDownload function simply downloading file but with no content inside. In downloaded file I could see something like:

```
[object Response]
```

I am getting 200 response from server. So I dont't think there is any issue with server side code. How can I handle it on client?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Will it suit you if you just redirected user to link to file? Browser will automatically handle it and download it.

Comment: Yes I guess its fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your `fileDownload` function which you do not post here. It's not clear what the first parameter is supposed to be but likely it is not the response object. Likely you at least need to pull the body out of the response and save that! The response body can be converted to a buffer object which could work (again it depends on what `fileDownload` is expecting):

`res.arrayBuffer().then(buffer => {
  fileDownload(buffer, item.file_name);
});`

Comment: When I printed response, I could not see any content from server in response object. I am not sure what FileResponse object exactly sends. In documentation they have given "A Response object that can be used to serve a static file from disk simply." Moreover, I am using react-file-download component https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-file-download . They have not mentioned what "data" means. But I assume it's file content. I suppose, my response object should contain atleast URL of the file. But that's  not the case.  When running through POSTMAN,  I  could see file/image in the body.